# How to match System date with log file date

Tags: shell, scripting

We have two database log files which are updating on timely manner.
Already monitoring script in place, during script runs it will check last 25 lines in log files and finds for below mentioned error id. if found alert will be triggered.

Problem: When script runs on 10 AM one database log file matching the current system date

```
10:50:01 SRV     9: Logout usernum 1020, userid  (739)
```

But for other database log file contain last update line @2AM like below.

```
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Unable to open /prd/dba/db/r86d/hlpempty9.lic, errno = 13. (1295)
```

I need your people help on modifying  this script.

So when this script run @10 AM based on server date if it is matching with database log file last line time then only script need to execute.

Script :

```
for DB in prdrey  hlpempty9 

do

. $DBA/script/mfgvars $DB

lgfile=$DBPATH/$DB.lg


if [ $? -eq 0 ]

then

echo "Error in Database : $DB \n " >> $ERRMSG

echo "===================================" >> $ERRMSG


tail -25 $lgfile | grep -E '\((1260|2527|5292|2249|541|1621|834|748|43|49|1154|1056|1055|796|5407|5410|797|4698|1280|5480|5409|6743|1049|1052|3773|3775|3784|2249|6743|9
407|831|9215|833|9450|9446|9445|6091|9318|9407|ERROR|FAILED)\)' >> $ERRMSG

echo "" >> $ERRMSG

fi
```

```
tail -25 prdrey.lg
10:38:47 SRV     4: Login usernum 1071, userid argonzalez (742)
10:39:04 SRV     9: Login usernum 1048, userid y280nxa, . (742)
10:39:29 SRV    20: Login usernum 928, userid breyes  (742)
10:40:00 SRV    21: Login usernum 827, userid pgresdba (742)
10:40:00 SRV    21: Logout usernum 827, userid  (739)
10:40:50 SRV    21: Login usernum 827, userid  (742)
10:42:05 SRV    22: Login usernum 826, userid y280elr (742)
10:42:08 SRV    26: Login usernum 825, userid snavarrete (742)
10:42:20 SRV     8: Usernum 1050 terminated abnormally. (794)
10:42:20 SRV     8: Logout usernum 1050, userid  (739)
10:42:58 SRV    20: Logout usernum 1055, userid  (739)
10:43:27 SRV    16: Logout usernum 835, userid  (739)
10:44:15 SRV     8: Login usernum 1055, userid y281oxc (742)
10:44:21 SRV    15: Usernum 1020 terminated abnormally. (794)
10:44:21 SRV    15: Logout usernum 1020, userid . (739)
10:44:52 SRV    31: Logout usernum 951, userid  (739)
10:45:00 SRV    31: Login usernum 1050, userid pgresdba (742)
10:45:00 SRV    31: Logout usernum 1050, userid  (739)
10:45:00 SRV    31: Login usernum 1050, userid pgresdba (742)
10:45:01 SRV    31: Logout usernum 1050, userid  (739)
10:45:15 SRV    26: Logout usernum 870, userid  (739)
10:48:59 SRV     9: Logout usernum 898, userid (739)
10:49:41 SRV    31: Login usernum 1050, userid y281oxc (742)
10:50:01 SRV     9: Login usernum 1020, userid pgresdba (742)
10:50:01 SRV     9: Logout usernum 1020, userid  (739)


tail -25 hlpempty9.lg
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Delay of Before-Image Flush (-Mf): 3. (4245)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Before-Image File I/O (-r -R): Reliable. (4247)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Before-Image Truncate Interval (-G): 60. (4249)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Before-Image Cluster Size: 16384. (4250)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Before-Image Block Size: 8192. (4251)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Number of Before-Image Buffers (-bibufs): 100. (4252)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: BI File Threshold size (-bithold): 0.0   Bytes. (9238)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: BI File Threshold Stall (-bistall): Disabled. (6552)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: After-Image Stall (-aistall): Not Enabled. (4254)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Number of After-Image Buffers (-aibufs): 50. (4256)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Storage object cache size (-omsize): 1024 (8527)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Maximum Number of Clients Per Server (-Ma): 3. (4257)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Maximum Number of Servers (-Mn): 3. (4258)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Minimum Clients Per Server (-Mi): 5. (4259)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Maximum Number of Users (-n): 31. (4260)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Host Name (-H): p5lp5. (4261)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Service Name (-S): hlpempty9. (4262)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Network Type (-N): tcp. (4263)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Character Set (-cpinternal): iso8859-1. (4264)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Parameter File: /prd/dba/etc/pf/db_empty.pf. (4282)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Minimum Port for Auto Servers (-minport): 13100. (5648)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Maximum Port for Auto Servers (-maxport): 14999. (5649)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: This broker supports both 4GL and SQL server groups. (8865)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Created shared memory with segment_id: 524305 (9336)
02:00:47 BROKER  0: Unable to open /prd/dba/db/r86d/hlpempty9.lic, errno = 13. (1295)
```

Comment: Why don't you fix the database sysdate?

Comment: Sorry Glenn database date cont be modified.

Comment: How are those logs generated? Can that process be fixed to account for the time difference?

Comment: Do you see what I'm getting at here? Fix the problem at the source, not downstream.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are nothing but our database log file. Logs are not generating from any source or destination.

Time format in database log file cont be changed.

Fyi... Our database log file contains historical information with date format.

My problem is in one log file it contains information up-to-date but other database log file don't have much updates init.
During this situation I don't want old date data to be checked its need to be ignored and generate alerts if it matching with system date only.